# Extraction of keys from json format data into new column

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'diff': [
    {'info': {'version': {'from': '2.0.0_1', 'to': '2.3.4_1'}}, 'paths': {'modified': {'/dummy': {'operations': {'added': ['PUT_1']}}}}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'PUT_1', 'path': '/dummy_1'}]}, 'components': {'schemas': {'added': ['ObjectOfObjects_1', 'inline_object_1', 'ObjectOfObjects_inner_1']}, 'requestBodies': {'added': ['inline_object_1', 'nested_response_1']}}},
    {'info': {'version': {'from': '2.0.0_2', 'to': '2.3.4_2'}}, 'paths': {'modified': {'/dummy': {'operations': {'added': ['PUT_2']}}}}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'PUT_2', 'path': '/dummy_2'}]}, 'components': {'schemas': {'added': ['ObjectOfObjects_2', 'inline_object_2', 'ObjectOfObjects_inner_2']}, 'requestBodies': {'added': ['inline_object_2', 'nested_response_2']}}}
] })
```

What I want to do is extract the keys from all such instances of `diff` column and store them under one single column.

Here is my original code for extraction of keys:

```
def try_get(obj, *keys, defaultVal=None):
    try:
        for k in keys: obj = obj[k]
        return obj
    except: return defaultVal

kSep = '.' 
extractKeys = [ ('info', 'version'), 
                ('paths', 'modified'), 
                ('endpoints', 'added'),
                ('components', 'schemas', 'added'), 
                ('components', 'requestBodies', 'added') ]
for kl in extractKeys:
    df[kSep.join(kl)] = df['diff'].map(lambda d: try_get(d, *kl))
```

I am not sure how can I modify this to get all the extracted keys under a new column. The output would be something like this:

```
    diff                                                            components
0   {'info': {'version': {'from': '2.0.0_1', 'to': '2.3.4_1'}}../   info-version,paths-modified,endpoints-added,components-schemas-added,components-requestBodies.added

1   {'info': {'version': {'from': '2.0.0_2', 'to': '2.3.4_2'}}../   info-version,paths-modified,endpoints-added,components-schemas-added,components-requestBodies.added
```

Any suggestions on how I could achieve the desired result?

Comment: How are you using `try_get`?

Comment: My apologies, I put the wrong code in the question. I updated the question with my current code which extracts all the keys separately and stores them as new columns with their values underneath. However, I only want to store the extracted keys for each diff row in a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, was a bit trivial I must say:

```
def try_get(obj, keys, defaultVal=None):
    try:
        for k in keys:
            obj = obj[k]
        return obj
    except:
        return defaultVal

def extract_keys(obj, extractKeys):
    extracted = []
    for kl in extractKeys:
        value = try_get(obj,kl)
        if value is not None:
            extracted.append(kSep.join(kl))
    return ','.join(extracted)

kSep = '.'
extractKeys = [
    ('info', 'version'),
    ('paths', 'modified'),
    ('endpoints', 'added'),
    ('components', 'schemas', 'added'),
    ('components', 'requestBodies', 'added')
]

df['components'] = df['diff'].map(lambda d: extract_keys(d, extractKeys))
```